# Pritunl: How to bind Pritunl Web-Interface to IPv4 AND IPv6?

Tags: debian, vpn

**Any ideas how to get Pritunl listing on IPv4 and IPv6?**

**systemctl status pritunl.service**

```
● pritunl.service - Pritunl Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pritunl.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-09-29 12:47:03 UTC; 4min 2s ago
 Main PID: 2409 (pritunl)
    Tasks: 19 (limit: 544)
   Memory: 109.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/pritunl.service
           ├─2409 /usr/lib/pritunl/bin/python /usr/lib/pritunl/bin/pritunl start
           └─2430 pritunl-web
```

**sudo netstat -tulpn | grep pritunl**

```
tcp6       0      0 :::443                 :::*                    LISTEN      1055/pritunl-web
```

**cat /etc/pritunl.conf**

```
{
    "debug": true,
    "bind_addr": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": 443,
    "log_path": "/var/log/pritunl.log",
    "temp_path": "/tmp/pritunl_%r",
    "local_address_interface": "auto",
    "mongodb_uri": ""
}
```

**cat /var/log/pritunl.log**

```
[undefined][2020-09-29 12:47:07,431][INFO] Starting setup server
[undefined][2020-09-29 12:47:07,432][INFO] Generating setup server ssl cert
```

Comment: Why do you think it is not listening on IPv4? This is Linux, after all.

Comment: See netstat -tulpn! Port 80 and 443 is bind to ::

Comment: Yes, that's normal. By default Linux listens on both IPv6 and IPv4 on an IPv6 socket.

Comment: No, this is not the case
`tcp6       0      0 :::80`

Comment: Um, yes, it is. I'm not sure why you're arguing about this. It is a very well known "feature" of Linux. That does not prove that it is not listening on IPv4.

Comment: Is there a way to make the default ipv4 only, @MichaelHampton?

I have tried running:
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
Changing the value of precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 10 to precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100 in /etc/gai.conf
As well as dropping ip6tables input/output traffic. All to no avail.

Any other suggestion? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the Pritunl documentation shows the uninstallation of **iptables**, but I did the test without uninstalling iptables and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

this is for anyone who comes here in the future that is having the same issue of not being able to reach pritunl web interface on AWS just after installation, also considering all configs are at default.
The issue is not with pritunl. Its actually your AWS instance security group that has to be modified.
Go to security groups and edit inbound rules to allow the needed ports